# Clojure macro for creating record

Tags: macros, clojure, record

I wrote a macro for creating a record

```
(defmacro def-entity [name & value]
 `(do
    (defrecord ~name (vector  ~@value))
    ))
```

and I created one entity

```
(def-entity p a b)
```

But when I try to create a concrete instance
    (def something (p. "a" "b"))
I get this message java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class user.p (repl-1:40). 
So I have to provide 3 parameters, like this
    (def someone (p. "a" "b" "x"))
And it puts the values like this

```
 (-> someone :a)
 "b"
 (-> neko :p)
 nil
```

I don't seem to understand what is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `defrecord` is itself a macro, and expects the fields of the record to be passed in as a vector literal, you should better avoid passing a symbol referring to a vector, and really construct a vector literal as part of your macro work:

```
(defmacro defentity [name & values]
  `(defrecord ~name ~(vec values)))
```

Which results in:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(defentity p a b))
(clojure.core/defrecord p [a b])
user=> (defentity Test foo bar)
user.Test
user=> (def s (Test. "foo" "bar"))
#'user/s
user=> s
#user.Test{:foo "foo", :bar "bar"}
```

In contrast, your version results in the following, which doesn't use a vector literal as input to `defrecord`:

```
user=> (macroexpand-1 '(def-entity p a b))
(do (clojure.core/defrecord p (clojure.core/vector a b)))
```

In facts, I can't even use your version in Clojure 1.4:

```
user=> (def-entity w x y)
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't use qualified name as parameter: clojure.core/vector, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I knew it was something basic... I use version Clojure 1.2...actually, was planing in upgrading to 1.4 these days...

Comment: Just please add one closing bracket at the end of the defmacro ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Use `[~@value]` instead of `(vector ~@value)`:

```
(defmacro def-entity [name & value]
 `(do
    (defrecord ~name [~@value])
    ))
```

Actually your variant doesn't work for me at all. `(def-entity p a b)` throws an exception. But I can suggest that `(def-entity p a b)` expands to `(defrecord p (vector a b))` and defrecord itself a macro and it takes it's second argument as list of fields. Second argument is `(vector a b)` - it's a list that contains 3 elements. So it creates record that has 3 fields: vector, a and b. Check what `(:vector someone)` returns.